# Finding the eigenvalues of $A^2$ and $A^{-1}$ from the characteristic polynomial of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In my question we are given a characteristic polynomial $x^3 - 4x^2 + x + 6$ for a matrix A and are told to find eigenvalues for both $A^{-1}$ and $A^2$. I just want to confirm that I am approaching this correctly. So I found the eigenvalues for matrix $A$, which are $x = -1, x = 2, x = 3$. Looking at the equation $A^n = P^{-1} D^n P$, where D is known because we have the eigenvalues, to find the eigenvalues of $A^2$ would we just have to do $(-1)^2, 2^2, 3^2$ ? and then a similar approach for $A^{-1}$.

Thank you.

Comment: Suppose $v$ is an EigenVector to, say, Eigenvalue 2. This means $Av = 2v$. Now, can you see what $A^{-1}v$ is, and what $A^2v$ is ?

Comment: In general, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, then for some vector $v$, $Av =\lambda v$. Then $A^2v = A(\lambda v) = \lambda Av = \lambda^2 v$. A similar argument can be made for $A^{-1}$.

Comment: @anon: The question asks for the actual eigenvalues of $A^2$, $A^{-1}$, not for their characteristic polynomials. So you'll have to factor a polynomial somewhere, why not just do it for the given one?

Comment: Oosp, I was confusing this with the many questions about traces of powers.

Answer (score 4):

HINTS
 Characteristic polynomial of $ A^{-1 }$is the polynimial whose roots are recripocal to roots of the given polynomial.